# Is the Sitecore Gold badge "Fanatic" recursive?

Tags: discussion

I have visited the Sitcore Exchange Site for 170 Days as of now.

The Fanatic badge is given on "Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days."

I want to know if, the sitecore Gold badge "Fanatic" recursive.

Comment: If it is not suited to the community standards, I can delete it :)

Comment: No, this is the perfect place for it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Recursive". But I assume you mean, if you get one more Gold Medal once you reach 200?

To that, the answer is "No".

[Is the "Fanatic" badge awarded multiple times?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292094/is-the-fanatic-badge-awarded-multiple-times)

Full run-down of the badges here: [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)